# How to print an array of strings with threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `String` array:

```
String[] messages = new String[]{"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"};
```

How do I print every value of it by separate threads? Every value is one thread. Threads are created the same amount as strings in array. Thanks!

I have only one class of Thread for this:

```
class Worker extends Thread{
}
```

Comment: **With a loop**, passing each individual string to the constructor of the `Worker` class. Or the index into the array, but passing the string itself is easier.

Comment: It is recommend to use `implements Runnable` instead of `extends Thread`. then use `new Thread(new Worker())` to instantiate the thread, or submit `Worker` to an execution service, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over each element of the array and construct a `Worker` from each one. The `Worker` class should override the `run` method to print the String.

```
class Worker extends Thread{
    private String message;
    public Worker(final String message){
       this.message = message;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
      System.out.println(message);
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       String[] messages = new String[]{"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"};
       for(final String message: messages){
         new Worker(message).start();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Executor service rather than extending `Thread`

The Executors framework was added to Java to relieve us app programmers of juggling threads. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Get an executor service from `Executors`.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() ;
```

Write your task as implementation of `Runnable`.
Notice that we are *not* extending `Thread`, in contrast to your code.

```
String[] messages = new String[]{ "aaaa" , "bbbb" , "cccc" } ;
for( String message : messages ) 
{
    es.submit(
         () -> { System.out.println( message ) ; }
    ) ;
}
```

In that code above, we use lambda syntax. You could just as well use traditional syntax.

When run using a thread pool of more than one thread, the order in which the tasks are executed is indeterminate. For example, when run the output may appear like this:

> aaaa

> cccc

> bbbb

```java
String[] messages = new String[]{ "aaaa" , "bbbb" , "cccc" } ;
for ( String message : messages )
{
    es.submit(
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run ( )
                {
                    System.out.println( message );
                }
            }
    );
}
```

By the way, lists are generally more convenient than arrays in Java.

```
List< String > messages = List.of( "aaaa" , "bbbb" , "cccc" ) ;
for( String message : messages ) 
{
    es.submit(
         () -> { System.out.println( message ) ; }
    )
}
```

See this entire example class [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/sE0YV8).

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.time.Instant ;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println( "Starting. " + Instant.now() );
        
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        List < String > messages = List.of( "aaaa" , "bbbb" , "cccc" );
        for ( String message : messages )
        {
            es.submit(
                    ( ) -> { System.out.println( message ); }
            );
        }

        System.out.println( "Tasks submitted to executor service. " + Instant.now() );
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis( 3 ) );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println( "Done. " + Instant.now() );
        
    }
}
```